# Java .txt file not found

Tags: java

For an assignment I need to call a method from another class SentenceChecker which uses a .txt file web2.txt. I have placed Cryptography.java (in which I'm calling the method), Cryptography.class, SentenceChecker.java, SentenceChecker.class and the web2.txt files all in the same folder, and changed permissions for read and write for everyone but file still cannot be found. Please advise me on what to do? This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class SentenceChecker {

final static int NUMBER_WORDS = 234936;

public static String[] wordList = initializeList();

public static int countEnglishWords(String input) {
 String[] allWords = input.split(" ");
 int totalWords = 0;
 for (int i=0; i < allWords.length; i++) {
 String transformed = allWords[i].toLowerCase();
 transformed = transformed.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
 if (findWord(transformed)) {
  totalWords++;
     }
 }

 return totalWords;
}

private static boolean findWord(String input) {
 int left = 0;
 int right = wordList.length - 1;
 while (left <= right) {
 int center = (left + right ) / 2;
 if (wordList[center].equals(input)) {
  return true;
 }

 if (wordList[center].compareTo(input) < 0) {
  left = center + 1;
 }
 else {
  right = center - 1;
 }
 }

 return false;
}

private static String[] initializeList() {
 try {
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("web2.txt"));
 String[] words = new String[NUMBER_WORDS];
 int i=0;

 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  words[i] = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
  i++;
 }
 return words;
 }
 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 System.out.println("WARNING: The file web2.txt was not found. Is it in the same directory as your other java files?");

 return null;
 }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your directory structure?

Comment: If you use Eclipse, use ctrl + shift + f. Helps a lot.

Comment: Try including the file path, not just the file name.

Comment: directory structure is /Users/name/Downloads/folder1/web2.txt

Answer (score 0):

The line `new File("web2.txt")` is a path which is relative to your **current working directory**, which is not necessarily where your files are.

Assuming `web2.txt` is in your classpath, you should try something like this:

```
URL path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("web2.txt");
File f = null;
if(path != null) { // file exists
     f = new File(path.toURI());
} else {
   //The file was not found, insert error handling here
}
```

Comment: Tried this but the error returned is cannot find symbol  : class URL.

Comment: So I need to figure out if it is in the classpath or not?

Comment: yes, another way you might want to consider is using a maven directory structure for your projects and place your file in the `resources/` directory, then do something like this `new File(SentenceChecker.class.getResource("web2.txt").toURI());`  but this requires you spend a bit of time getting familiar with the maven file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to put it in a location (like your desktop for example) and using the path "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\web2.txt" to access it.